# How to divide a sentence into a string array of seperate words?

Tags: c#, arrays

In the process of making my memory r/w library I thought of making a method called `AssemblyToHex` but for that I would either need a already made assembler or make one myself. I thought of making my own. Getting to the point, the way this method would works is like this:

```
public string AssemblyToHex(string instruction)
{
//Divide "instruction" into string array e.g. "mov eax,[edi+04]" = new[] { "mov", "eax", "[edi+04]" };

//Here it will compare the opcode to its hex representation (which wont be a issue to make)

//returns the Hex representation of the instruction.
}
```

How do I divide the instruction into a string array of words? I know there is a `.Split()` function and I think that's something I will need but idk what to do. I need to divide where there are commas and spaces e.g.:

`cvtsi2ss xmm0,edx = { "cvtsi2ss", "xmm0", "edx" }`

`push 00 = { "push", "00" }`

`mov [ecx+0C],0x447A0000 = { "mov", "[ecx+0C]", "0x447A0000" }`

Comment: .Split(new Char [] {' ' , ',' }); Can you try this?

Comment: MSDN documentation is your friend: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx . I am genuinely curious at which point of the process you got stuck once you had established that `Split` was the method you wanted...

Comment: Dieter B: That works xD   |   Chris: well I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
mystring.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

If you don't use the option, "cvtsi2ss xmm0, edx" will give you an empty string entry in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var instructionArray = instruction.Split(' ', ',');
```